# Is it possible to render image created by Boost GIL in an Electron app?

Tags: c++, boost, electron

Currently electron has native image support to load image from a JPEG or PNG image or buffer but is it possible to load image created by boost gil to load it in electron app. The images are being generated from a pdf by passing the pdf path to a native node module which converts the pdf into RGB image type using boost.

Comment: Hi there & welcome to StackOverflow! Your question is a little bit vague. Could you add some code that you already have (but of course only code pertaining to this exact problem). Show how you would like to load an image in the Electron app. Show what you're doing with Boost GIL. It'll be easier for others to help once those goalposts are there. Please don't post your full code - just minimal, abstracted examples that help us understand what you're up to.

Comment: Yes this is possible.